# Having trouble with compiling rust for custom target

Tags: rust, operating-system

I have been following this tutorial for writing an OS in rust: https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/
As soon as I try to compile it with the x86_64-blog_os.json target, it throws this linker error:

```
error: linking with 'cc' failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH= ......

..... = note: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section '.text'

          /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile 'compiler_builtins' (build script) due to previous error
```

When I was installing rust the first time on my machine, i accidentally stopped the installation script while it was running. I thought this was the problem so i deleted rust and reinstalled it.
Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

x86_64-blog_os.json file:

```
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

.cargo/config.toml file:

```
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
```

Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "blog_os"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
```

Toolchain: nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc: 1.72.0-nightly

Edit: I just found out this happens when i try to compile anywhere, not just this target. Updating toolchain doesn't work

Edit 2.: I solved the issue. There was a problem with binutils. All i needed to do was `apt purge` it and reinstall it. Closing the question.

Comment: Have you added `build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]` to `[unstable]` section in `.cargo/config.toml`?

Comment: yes, i tried it with and without the build-std-features. still the exact same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It looks like an issue with Scrt1.o. All i needed to do is delete binutils and reinstall it.

`sudo apt purge binutils`

`sudo apt install binutils`